# Is Democracy 3 deterministic?

Tags: democracy-3

All of the systems in this game are very complex. Policies have all sorts of knock-on effects, and voters are effected by any number of them.

But if I perform the exact same actions in multiple runs of the game, will I get exactly the same result?

It would be nice to know the answer to this question right down to the individual voter level, but probably only the developer could answer that, so I'd settle for an answer at the election level.

Comment: You might want to read up on general Chaos Theory...

Comment: @Shadur ... in Eve, we call it "The Sandbox"

Comment: I can't say for certain, not being intimately familiar with the game... but it's *highly* unlikely. Random chance is a go-to method of adding complexity and interest in game design, *especially* in simulation games, and I'd be very surprised if Democracy 3 was any exception.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure I agree that random chance is that much of a given. If the simulation is complex enough, with enough variables and enough interdependencies, then even small changes to a couple of variables can have all sorts of follow-on effects. Which to me is more interesting than just rolling the dice each time you play. My gut feel was actually that Democracy 3 probably *is* deterministic.

Comment: The game can't be deterministic because some of the monthly events are random, unless it stores the save to prevent you from reloading an event. I don't have the game installed but someone should check if the seed is saved

Comment: Only one way to find out, save a game, and make a set of choices, load the save state, make the same set of choices. Repeat until either a deviation occurs in plays, or you are satisfied a "track" has been found. I will start research now, and report back with findings soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.positech.co.uk/democracy3/modding.html, where the game model is described. Most of the game turns out to be deterministic, however some things like [dilemmas](http://www.positech.co.uk/democracy3/modding_dilemmas.html) can use `_random_` as input, i.e. some events happen randomly. As an example, my Prime Minister was recently assassinated, but upon reloading the autosave (the game crashed) he had instea survived.

So **tl;dr**: If you do everything the same, the randomness of some events will still yield a different outcome which may be severely different.

Comment: That's good enough for me, seems there's definitely some random elements in the engine.

Answer (score 3):

According to a few let's plays I've watched, the game starts with *different* stats every game. So if that was correct, *doing the same thing every time would lead to a different outcome for each game.*

Comment: I guess that technically answers `"if I perform the exact same actions..., will I get exactly the same result"`, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's not deterministic. The game's initialisation may be randomised, but the simulation may be deterministic if you save right at the start and then play from that point, multiple times, in exactly the same way.